# Module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'SGD'. Google Collab

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I have notebook created on Google Collab.
For work I need some functions of keras library.

I imported them

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras import regularizers
from keras import optimizers
```

After running occurred this problem.

```
     54     model.compile(
---> 55      optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=lr),
     56      loss = loss_func,
     57      metrics = ["acc"]
```

AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'SGD'

I tried this way

```
model.compile(
     optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=lr),
     loss = loss_func,
     metrics = ["accuracy"]
    )
```

I haven't issues with SGD but I have the same issue with Sequential.

What will be the right solution in this case? Why doesn't first way work?

Comment: This might have to do with your keras version and keras having been integrated into tf some time ago. In general it seems you are recommended to use `from tensorflow.keras import <module>` instead of `from keras import <module>`

Answer (score 9):

Use tf.keras.optimizers.SGD instaed of optimizers.SGD

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to use `tensorflow.keras.optimizers` instead of just `keras.optimizers`.